# php need help to create nested array using parsing html element

Tags: php, html, arrays, parsing

I need a help to create a nested array from  element of html file using dom method this is the code

```
<?php
$html = '
    <p>text1</p>
    <ul>
        <li>list-a1</li>
        <li>list-a2</li>
        <li>list-a3</li>
    </ul>
    <p>text2</p>
    <ul>
        <li>list-b1</li>
        <li>list-b2</li>
        <li>list-b3</li>
    </ul>
    <p>text3</p>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('p') as $link) {
    echo $link->nodeValue."\n", PHP_EOL;
}
foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('ul') as $link) {
    $books = $link->getElementsByTagName('li');
    foreach ($books as $book) {
        echo $book->nodeValue, PHP_EOL;
        // $links3[] = array( $ii=> $book->nodeValue, );
        //$ii++;
    }
}
?>
```

and this is the 
Program Output:

```
text1
text2
text3
list-a1
list-a2
list-a3
list-b1
list-b2
list-b3
```

but i need to get this output in the same order of original html

```
text1
list-a1
list-a2
list-a3
text2
list-b1
list-b2
list-b3
text3
```

without using preg or replace method !!!

Comment: show your expected outcome in exact way. not in text

Comment: you mean should i delete `foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('ul') as $link) `

Comment: thank you but wasn't the soution check this (https://eval.in/708775)

Comment: Didn't you ask this exact question yesterday?

Comment: not exactly , but no one understand what i need exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To print the values

```
<?php

    $html = '
        <p>text1</p>
        <ul>
            <li>list-a1</li>
            <li>list-a2</li>
            <li>list-a3</li>
        </ul>
        <p>text2</p>
        <ul>
            <li>list-b1</li>
            <li>list-b2</li>
            <li>list-b3</li>
        </ul>
        <p>text3</p>
    ';

    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($html);

    foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0)->childNodes as $node) {
        if ($node->nodeType === XML_ELEMENT_NODE) {
            if($node->nodeName == 'p'){
                    echo $node->nodeValue."\n", PHP_EOL;

            }elseif($node->nodeName == 'ul'){
                $books = $node->getElementsByTagName('li');
                foreach ($books as $book) {
                    echo $book->nodeValue, PHP_EOL;
                }

            }
        }
    }

    ?>
```

Output

```
text1 
list-a1 
list-a2 
list-a3 
text2 
list-b1 
list-b2 
list-b3 
text3
```

To print in the form of nested array

```
<?php

$html = '
    <p>text1</p>
    <ul>
        <li>list-a1</li>
        <li>list-a2</li>
        <li>list-a3</li>
    </ul>
    <p>text2</p>
    <ul>
        <li>list-b1</li>
        <li>list-b2</li>
        <li>list-b3</li>
    </ul>
    <p>text3</p>
';

$result = array();

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$i = 0;
foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0)->childNodes as $node) {
    if ($node->nodeType === XML_ELEMENT_NODE) {
        if($node->nodeName == 'p'){
            $result[$node->nodeName][$i] = $node->nodeValue;

        }elseif($node->nodeName == 'ul'){
            $result[$node->nodeName][$i] = array();
            $books = $node->getElementsByTagName('li');
            foreach ($books as $book) {
                $result[$node->nodeName][$i][$book->nodeName][] = $book->nodeValue;
            }

        }
        $i++;
    }
}
var_dump($result);

?>
```

Comment: can you do that with arrays  i want save it in nested one!!

Comment: Can you give a sample output?

Comment: I have edit the answer with the nested array. I hope it is what you are looking for.

Comment: this method work only with this example not working  in my project  i think that  because this line ` if ($node->nodeType === XML_ELEMENT_NODE`  i am using `include('simple_html_dom.php');` and `$url = 'http://www.example.com/ex.php';`

Comment: thank you for your  time but it solve only the example not working on my project , is it necessary to use  `$node->nodeType === XML_ELEMENT_NODE`

Comment: i will try to make some changes i am so close to finish my little project but i still stuck with this , and what make it worst is those dislike XD

Comment: Not required to use it. but you can also use 1 rather than XML_ELEMENT_NODE

Comment: i will study your code , cuz i am newbie but it look very interesting and short thank you again god save you